# How to transfer a java web app from eclipse to a server

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I have a working java web app set up in eclipse using tomcat and maven, which is accessible via //localhost:8080 when I run the program. What are the necessary steps to now put this application on a website so that it is accessible from anywhere, either with a personal server that I set up or with a web service such as Azure or Amazon web services?

Comment: Have you heard of `Jetty` or `Tomcat`?

Comment: @user2004685 Yes, I used Tomcat when developing my program, but how do I make this more than just //localhost:8080

Comment: You'll have to simply install the `Tomcat` on your server and then transfer your `WAR` file. You can then access it on: `<serverip>:<port>` from anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Though the deployment depends on the application you developed, but a simple solution can be to export the project as a `war` file and deploy it in the tomcat webapps directory.

Alternatively you can also use the admin feature of Tomcat. But one can properly answer your question, if we have the details of your project.